# Check if an element is present in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

The function I am using now to check this is the following:

```
function inArray(needle,haystack)
{
    var count=haystack.length;
    for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        if(haystack[i]===needle){return true;}
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Of course, if your array is sorted you could do a binary-search instead.  Or if each value in the array is always unique you could use a map-based approach instead.

Comment: The `==` operator? Do you really want to explicitly allow type coercion? Of course not. Therefore, use the `===` operator instead.

Comment: It's smart to declare `count` before the loop. You could also replace those two lines with just `for(var i=haystack.length; i--;)`

Comment: For numbers one can also use the `in` operator (e.g. `(5 in array)`. It will probably be faster than other options, but won't work for string or objects or any other non-number.

Answer (score 1353, accepted):

**ECMAScript 2016** incorporates an [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method for arrays that specifically solves the problem, and so is now the preferred method.

```
[1, 2, 3].includes(2);     // true
[1, 2, 3].includes(4);     // false
[1, 2, 3].includes(1, 2);  // false (second parameter is the index position in this array at which to begin searching)
```

*As of JULY 2018, this [has been implemented](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes) in almost all **major** browsers, if you need to support an older browser a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#polyfill) is available.*

Edit: Note that this returns false if the item in the array is an object. This is because similar objects are two different objects in JavaScript.

Comment: What's a polyfill?

Comment: @nirvanaswap A polyfill is a script you can use to ensure that any browser will have an implementation of something you're using. In this case, you'd add a script that checks `if ("includes" in Array.prototype)` and if not, implements it (using a solution like [Benny's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18101063/2099674), for instance). The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (also linked to in this answer) actually provide one for you.

Comment: i used this like below, and working fine. And don't push duplicate value. Thanks a lot!!

this.state.UpdatedfriendList.includes(s.valueKey)===false? this.state.UpdatedfriendList.push(s.valueKey):'';

Comment: How will be the performance if I have an array with 900 values?

Comment: @PrithiviRaj It would be linear time, so performance impact would be directly proportional to the size of the array.

Comment: Using widely supported `myArray.indexOf(myVal) > -1` is same thing but safer

Comment: @Alister : Please give clarification . 
[1, 2, 3].includes(1, 2) // true  . for me it is giving the 'false' value.
how come it is true. i checked in google chrome browser.

The above condition will give results as  --- true false false false false

Comment: Too bad this isn't supported in Google Apps Script

Comment: Internet Explorer is not supported :(

Comment: @CésarLeón Who wants to support that abomination? Only use this answer if you don't have to worry about supporting IE, otherwise there's other choices available on this page that are IE-friendly...

Comment: The polyfill link is broken.

Answer (score 491):

**Code:**

```
function isInArray(value, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}
```

**Execution:**

```
isInArray(1, [1,2,3]); // true
```

**Update (2017):**

In modern browsers which follow the ECMAScript 2016 (ES7) standard, you can use the function [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), which makes it way more easier to check if an item is present in an array:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];
const value = 1;
const isInArray = array.includes(value);
console.log(isInArray); // true
```

Comment: !==-1 [extra chars]

Comment: `indexOf` not working carefully in IE browser.

Comment: @totaldesign *not working carefully*, do you mean it is working *carelessly* in IE? :D

Comment: works in node 4.4.7

Comment: To my knowledge, ES2016 (which includes the includes method for Arrays) is the seventh edition of ECMAScript. The 6. edition is ES 2015 and does not contain "includes". Please correct.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#7th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2016

Comment: @Juergen Thanks for the hint! I updated the content.

Answer (score 103):

Just use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
haystack.indexOf(needle) >= 0
```

If you want to support old Internet Explorers (< IE9), you'll have to [include your current code as a workaround though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers).

Unless your list is sorted, you need to compare every value to the needle. Therefore, both your solution and `indexOf` will have to execute `n/2` comparisons on average. However, since `indexOf` is a built-in method, it may use additional optimizations and will be slightly faster in practice. Note that unless your application searches in lists extremely often (say a 1000 times per second) or the lists are huge (say 100k entries), the speed difference will not matter.

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` isn't implemented in IE8.

Comment: Not supported in IE (maybe only in 9) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers

Comment: This is noted on the page, but it's worth mentioning as part of the answer:  `indexOf` is a relatively new addition to JavaScript, and is not supported in IE version prior to 9.0.  Also worth noting that `indexOf` will still be O(n), so if the OP meant "better" in terms of speed/performance this won't really be any better, just shorter.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal True, although the argument is very easy. Added a paragraph about performance, just in case that performance is what the OP meant with `better`.

Comment: Hi, I meant better speed-wise mostly. Length of code is important, but less so than speed. The array is not sorted, it's created while being checked. If a string value is not in the array it is added.

Comment: @Francisc - Then you might try a map-based approach.  Then your `inArray()` implementation could be as simple as `return haystack[needle] != undefined;`.

Answer (score 49):

I benchmarked it multiple times on Google Chrome 52, but feel free to copypaste it into any other browser's console.

---

### ~ 1500 ms, includes (~ 2700 ms when I used the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes))

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
var result = 0;

var start = new Date().getTime();
for(var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
  if(array.includes("test") === true){ result++; }
}
console.log(new Date().getTime() - start);
```

---

### ~ 1050 ms, indexOf

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
var result = 0;

var start = new Date().getTime();
for(var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
  if(array.indexOf("test") > -1){ result++; }
}
console.log(new Date().getTime() - start);
```

---

### ~ 650 ms, custom function

```
function inArray(target, array)
{

/* Caching array.length doesn't increase the performance of the for loop on V8 (and probably on most of other major engines) */

  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
  {
    if(array[i] === target)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false; 
}

var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]; 
var result = 0;

var start = new Date().getTime();
for(var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
  if(inArray("test", array) === true){ result++; }
}
console.log(new Date().getTime() - start);
```

Comment: ~ 950 / 750 / 650 on my laptop. I just changed array to ['df','ff',2,3,4,5,6,333,8,9] and got ~ 950 / 900 / 3150

Comment: 130-160 / 120-160 / 110-130 but `some`, as i expect is two time faster `if (array.some(i => i>2)){ result++; }` - about 50-90 ms

Answer (score 27):

Single line code.. will return true or false

```
!!(arr.indexOf("val")+1)
```

Comment: bc everyone loves tilde `!!~arr.indexOf("val")`

Comment: or just use `~arr.indexOf("val")`. 0 = falsey, other numbers = truthy

Comment: uhhh, 0 should be true because it is found as the first element in the array?

Comment: Best solution if you have to cater towards IE11.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `indexOf` But not working well in the last version of internet explorer.
**Code:**

```
function isInArray(value, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}
```

**Execution:**

```
isInArray(1, [1,2,3]); // true
```

I suggest you use the following code:

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
 var length = haystack.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
 if (haystack[i] == needle)
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Since ECMAScript6, one can use Set :

```js
var myArray = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var mySet = new Set(myArray);
var hasB = mySet.has('B'); // true
var hasZ = mySet.has('Z'); // false
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [_contains](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) function from the underscore.js library to achieve this:

```
if (_.contains(haystack, needle)) {
  console.log("Needle found.");
};
```

Comment: underscore library just for this?

Comment: Not necessarily, as the developer may already be using Underscore in their app for other features. Using Underscore is one solution among many.

Answer (score 4):

In lodash you can use [_.includes](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) (which also aliases to _.contains)

You can search the whole array:

```
_.includes([1, 2, 3], 1); // true
```

You can search the array from a starting index:

```
_.includes([1, 2, 3], 1, 1);  // false (begins search at index 1)
```

Search a string:

```
_.includes('pebbles', 'eb');  // true (string contains eb)
```

Also works for checking simple arrays of objects:

```
_.includes({ 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40 }, 'fred');    // true
_.includes({ 'user': 'fred', 'age': false }, false);  // true
```

One thing to note about the last case is it works for primitives like strings, numbers and booleans but cannot search through arrays or objects

```
_.includes({ 'user': 'fred', 'age': {} }, {});   // false
_.includes({ 'user': [1,2,3], 'age': {} }, 3);   // false
```