# Check that the array is unique

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: Determine whether an array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/javascript-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)

```
var thelist = new Array();
function addlist(){
thelist.push(documentgetElementById('data').innerHTML);
}
```

How can I check that the data I push does not already exsist in array `thelist`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var thelist = []; // Use the array literal, not the constructor.
function addlist(){

  // get the data we want to make sure is unique
  var data = documentgetElementById('data').innerHTML;

  // make a flag to keep track of whether or not it exists.
  var exists = false;

  // Loop through the array
  for (var i = 0; i < thelist.length; i++) {

    // if we found the data in there already, flip the flag
    if (thelist[i] === data) {
      exists = true;

      // stop looping, once we have found something, no reason to loop more.
      break;
    }
  }

  // If the data doesn't exist yet, push it on there.
  if (!exists) {
    thelist.push(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Might as well put a `break;` inside the `if` block that's inside the `for` loop

Comment: And use [`Array#indexOf`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14), as nearly all engines have it (use a polyfill for those that don't). In hopes that the native implementation might be faster than your loop (which is by no means guaranteed).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, that basically removes the whole `for` loop stuff and allows for a one/two liner. I was gonna post an answer with that, but then this answer was here that basically does that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about IE < 9 you could also use the Array method "some".
Just have a look at this example:

```
var thelist = [1, 2, 3];

function addlist(data) {

    alreadyExists = thelist.some(function (item) {
        return item === data
    });

    if (!alreadyExists) {
        thelist.push(data);
    }
}
addlist(1);
addlist(2);
addlist(5);

console.log(thelist);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C7PBf/

Some determines whether at least one element with given constraint (callbacks return value === true) does exist or not.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned about IE version 8 or lower, you can use `Array.filter`:

```
var thelist = new Array();
function addlist(){
    var val = documentgetElementById('data').innerHTML;
    var isInArray = theList.filter(function(item){
        return item != val
    }).length > 0;

    if (!isInArray)
        thelist.push(val);
}
```

Or, you could use `Array.indexOf`:

```
var thelist = new Array();
function addlist(){
    var val = documentgetElementById('data').innerHTML;
    var isInArray = theList.indexOf(val) >= 0;

    if (!isInArray)
        thelist.push(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `underscore.js` : [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org)
Then you can check the array as

```
_.contains(thelist, 'value you want to check');

// The full example
var thelist = new Array();
function addlist(){
   var data = documentgetElementById('data').innerHTML;
   if(!_.contains(thelist, data)) theList.push(data);
}
```

or you can add the values to the array without concerning the duplicate values, and after the adding process is finished, you can remove the duplicate elements by

```
theList = _.uniq(theList);
```

The second method of course less efficient.

Comment: A whole library is overkill for a simple task such as this.

Comment: True but the answer is still correct, and perhaps useful if there are other functionality in the OP code that could be simplified with a library.

Comment: @MarkThomas It is more simple and easy, but not very good if you want to learn JavaScript or prefer Vanilla JS (like me).