# How do I iterate through a list of items in a Ext.dataview.List

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm currently trying to find out how to set items to be selected on a list in ST2.
I've found the following:

```
l.select(0, true);
l.select(1, true);
```

which would select the first 2 items on my list.   But the data coming from the server is in csv format string with the ids of the items in the list to be selected.

```
e.g. "4, 10, 15"
```

So I currently have this code at the moment.

```
doSetSelectedValues = function(values, scope) {
    var l = scope.getComponent("mylist");
    var toSet = values.split(",");

    // loop through items in list
    // if item in list has 'id' property matching whatever is in the toSet array then select it.
}
```

The problem is I can't seem to find a way of iterating over the items in the list and then inspect the "id" property of the item to see if it matches with the item in the array.

```
l.getItems()
```

Doesn't seem to return an array of items. The list is populated via a store with the "id" & "itemdesc" properties. I just want to be able to select those items from a csv string.  I've scoured the Api on this and I can't seem to find a way of iterating over the items in the list and being able to inspect its backing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doSetSelectedValues = function(values, scope) {

    var l = scope.getComponent("mylist"),
        store = l.getStore(),
        toSet = values.split(",");

    Ext.each(toSet, function(id){
        l.select(store.getById(id), true);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

the `Ext.List`'s items are not the items you are looking for. The items under the `Ext.List` object are those:

```
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    fullscreen: true,
    itemTpl: '{title}',
    store: theStore,
    **items: [item1, item2]**
});
```

Granted, usually an `Ext.List` doesn't have items like these. What you are looking for are the **`Ext.Store`** items. The `Ext.Store` items are the exact same items in the same order as presented in the `Ext.List`.
To iterate over those, and select the corresponding items in the list, do the following:

```
var s = l.getStore();
var itemIndicesToSelect = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < s.data.items.length ; i++){
    if (arrayContainsValue(toSet, s.data.items[i].data.id)){
        itemIndicesToSelect.push(i);
    }
}

for (var i = 0 ; i < itemIndicesToSelect.length ; i++){
     l.selectRange(itemIndicesToSelect[i], itemIndicesToSelect[i], true);
}
```

You would have to implement the function arrayContainsValue ([one possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/javascript-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)).