# javascript - checking if input corresponds to 1 array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm having an array:

```
var something = ["1","2","3","4"] ;
```

I'll ask the user in a prompt to pick a number.
if it corresponds to any value in the array it triggers something.

My question is: How do i check if the input corresponds to any array value?

```
if(something === "input"){
    console.log("u picked a good number");
}
```

Of course if statement i have now is incorrect, but how do i make it check every value in the array, and see if anything corresponds?

Would be awsome if someone could help me on this one! ;)

thxx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Determine whether an array contains a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/javascript-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value) - use `indexOf()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays have an [`indexOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which returns the index at which the argument was found in the array, or -1 if it wasn't found:

```
if (something.indexOf(input) > -1) {
    // In the array!
}
```

Note that some older browsers don't support this method, but there is a polyfill in the MDN article linked to above.

Comment: Thx! this helped me alot. it works :) you made me a bit wiser!