# is a value in a given list of values using javascript?

Tags: javascript, boolean, set

How to find out if a given value is among some values? Similar to the `IN` operator in SQL or what you might expect from sets.  Let's suppose set is `{male,female,xyz}`. I want to find if male is in the set.

Answer (score 1):

The [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator does exist in JavaScript. But it checks whether a property exists on an object.

You can use an object hash or an array:

```
var values = {male: true, female: true, xyz: true}
var valueToSearch = 'female';

valueToSearch in values; //true

var values = ['male', 'female', 'xyz']

values.indexOf(valueToSearch) !== -1 // true
```

EDIT:
Using a RegExp:

```
if(pattern.test(search)) {
   //search found
}
```

Comment: var pattern=new RegExp(male|female|xyz);  var search="malee"; i want to know search is in pattern or not in terms of true false....in my example answer should be false

Comment: Please refer to the documentation on RegExp https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: i tried with.. var pattern = new RegExp((male|female|xyz),"i");
var search = 'male';
if(pattern.test(search)) {
   //search found
}

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `indexOf`. Check this example to understand how to use it:

[Determine whether an array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/javascript-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in an array you can use [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

```
var find = 'male';
var haystack = ['female', 'male', 'xyz'];

alert((haystack.indexOf(find) >= 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Object

```
var objNames = {
    "Michigan": "MI",
    "New York": "NY",
    "Coffee": "yes, absolutely"
};
```

## Array

```
var arrNames = [
    "Michigan", "New York", "Coffee"
]
```

## Function

```
function isIn(term, list) {
    var i, len;
    var listType = Object.prototype.toString.call(list);

    if (listType === '[object Array]') {
            for (i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (term === listType[i]) { return true; }
            }
            return false;
    }

    if (listType === '[object Object]') {
        return !!list[term]; // bang-bang is used to typecast into a boolean
    }

    // What did you sent to me?!
    return false;
}
```

## Usage

```
var michiganExists = isIn('Michigan', objNames); // true
```

## Note

I didn't use indexOf because the op didn't mention browser support, and indexOf doesn't work with all versions of Internet Explorer (gross!)