# Checking radio buttons according to an Array

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing four numbers:

```
var players = [0,3,4,2];
```

I have some radio buttons to select a name:

```
<h3 id="question">Which player would you like?</h3>

<input type="radio" name="choice" value="0" id="answ1">
<label for="choice" id="choice_1">John</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" id="answ2">
<label for="choice" id="choice_2">Wayne</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="2" id="answ3">
<label for="choice" id="choice_3">Steven</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="3" id="answ4">
<label for="choice" id="choice_4">Jack</label>
<br>
<button id="back">Back</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

When the radio buttons display I would like the first radio button to be checked i.e. The player John. I know I could simply set `autofocus` or use jQuery but I want to do it with vanilla Javascript. The idea is that the player names will change dynamically and the player will be selected based on the value in the array i.e. number 3 of the second set of players will be chosen.

Thanks, any help appreciated.

EDIT:

John will be chosen because the first value of the array is 0 and John is the first choice i.e. 0 = 1st choice, 1 = second choice etc

Comment: Yes but I want to do this with vanilla JavaScript... unless this makes it too difficult.

Comment: I don't get how 'John' was picked based on that array

Comment: oh yeah I don't think it's clear. I'll try edit it.

Comment: If you just want the first radio button to be checked, try: `document.querySelector('input[name="choice"]').checked = true;`

Comment: But then when the next set of players are named I want the fourth one chosen because it corresponds to the next value in the array which is 3. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah. I get it. Give me a minute

Comment: Check my demo below:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278100/checking-radio-buttons-according-to-an-array/21278447#21278447

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment/decrement an index value when the Next/Back buttons are clicked, and then set the `checked` property to true for the radio button with that index.

```
var players = [0, 3, 4, 2, 1];
var i = 0;
var choices = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="choice"]');
choices[players[i]].checked = true;
document.getElementById('back').onclick = function () {
    if (i > 0) {
        i--;
        choices[players[i]].checked = true;
    }
}
document.getElementById('next').onclick = function () {
    if (i < players.length - 1) {
        i++;
        choices[players[i]].checked = true;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/z6skD/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try my approach using `array.indexOf`

```
var players = [0, 3, 4, 2];
var ins = document.getElementsByName('choice');
for (var i = 0; i < ins.length; i++) {
    if (players.indexOf(parseInt(ins[i].value, 10)) > -1) {
        ins[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

**FYI:**

1. The radio button is grouped under the name **`check`** so multiple
   select is not going to work in your case.
2. This code will fail in older version of IE and [here is the workaround.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181586/1671639)

Answer (score 0):

```
        var players = [0,3,1,2];
        var currentPosInArray = 0;
        window.onload = function() {
            ChangeSelectedRadio();
        }

        function ChangeSelectedRadio() {
            var radio = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
            var arrItem = players[currentPosInArray];
            for (var i =0; i< radio.length; i++ ){
                radio[i].checked = false;
            }
            if (radio[arrItem]) {
                radio[arrItem].checked = true;
            }
        }

        function ChangeSelection(forward) {
            if (forward) {
                currentPosInArray++;
            }
            else {
                currentPosInArray--;
            }
            if (currentPosInArray < 0) {
                currentPosInArray = players.length -1; //if is in first pos and click "Back" - go to last item in array
            }
            else if (currentPosInArray >= players.length) {
                currentPosInArray = 0; //if is in last position and click "Next" - go to first item in array
            }
            ChangeSelectedRadio();
        }
```

where `ChangeSelection(forward)` is event to buttons.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9RWsp/1/

Comment: I don't think you need to manually un-check all the other radio-buttons. Since they all have the same name, only one of them can be checked at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
var players = [0,3,4,2];
var firstValue = players[0];
var firstInput = document.querySelector("input[type=radio][name=choice][value='"+firstValue+"']");
firstInput.checked = true;
```