# Jquery Array/String Search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I been working a script that will check if the new input 'value/string' is already exist, but so far I cant find the correct/efficient solution.

```
<input type="text" class="existingKeywords" value="string1, string2, string3">
<input type="text" class="newKeyword" value="">
```

the value of .newKeyword will defend on user input and once submit button is click, it will check if the newKeyword.val() already exist from .existingKeywords.val(); separated by ','

I tried but returns 'json parse unexpected character'

```
  var arr    = JSON.parse("[" + $('.existingKeywords').val() + "]");
  var newKey = $('.newKeyword').val();
  if( jQuery.inArray (newKey, arr) ){
    alert('Found!');
  }
```

Can someone tell me, why its not working or Is there a better approach than this?

Thanks!

---

Thank you so much guys, the script is now perfectly working. I want to 'Vote Up' everyone's answer but it requires 15 Reputation, and as of this writing I only have 13 reputation. And again gracias everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Determine whether an array contains a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/javascript-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because this line:

```
var arr    = JSON.parse("[" + $('.existingKeywords').val() + "]");
```

interprets this way:

```
var arr    = JSON.parse("[string1, string2, string3]");
```

which is not a correct JSON - strings inside shall be in quotes, otherwise `JSON.Parse` doesn't know what is `string1`.

As other suggested you need to use `split` here instead, I'd like to add only trimming the leading/trailing spaces:

```
var arr = $('.existingKeywords').val().split(',').map(function(s) { return s.trim();})
var newKey = $('.newKeyword').val().trim();
if( $.inArray (newKey, arr) != -1 ){
  alert('Found!');
}
```

But why don't you use `select` with multiple choises? It is more convenient that type keywords I think.

Comment: Thank you Mr. GRaAL, my script is now working perfect, and everyone's answer is acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the good old `String.split()`?

Something like this:

```
var arr = $('.existingKeywords').val().split(',');
var newKey = $('.newKeyword').val();

if( jQuery.inArray(newKey, arr) != -1 ){
    alert('Found!');
}
```

Comment: I tried but the .inArray() always return true, whatever the newKeyword's value.

Comment: This is because `inArray` does not return true/false. When keyword is found it returns index in array - from `0` to `arr.length-1`. When not found it returns `-1` which is also interpreted as `true`

Comment: thanks to Mr. GRaAL and your answer, its now working perfect!

Comment: I will be back here once, my reputation reaches 15 and Vote Up everyone's answer. ^__^

Answer (score 1):

```
 var arr    = $('.existingKeywords').val().split(',');
  var newKey = $('.newKeyword').val();
  if( $.inArray (newKey, arr) ){
    alert('Found!');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check for case-insensitive duplicate values as well  and please try getting values of input with ID instead of class it is safer...

```
  var array    = $('.existingKeywords').val().split(',');
  var new_array =[] ;

  for(var key in array)
  new_array.push(array[key].toLowerCase());

  var newkeyword = $('.newKeyword').val().toLowerCase();

 if( $.inArray (newkeyword , new_array)!== -1 ){
     //found your value
  }
```