# Remove all items of an array if they exist in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have a array in which I add different categories of items from other arrays:

For example, 2 arrays countries and languages:

```
countries = ['US', 'UK', 'Canada'];
languages = ['English', 'French', 'German'];
```

Which I use to populate another array:

```
items = ['US', 'French'];
```

In items I can only have one item from countries and languages so each time I want to add a country in items I have to remove the other country which was already in items.

For now the way I am doing it is looping through countries and languages to check if the item is in items but I am sure there is a more elegant way to do it, using underscore.js for example:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < country.length; i ++){
  if (items.indexOf(country[i]) > -1){
       items.splice($.inArray(country[i], items),1)
  }
}
```

Does anyone have a simple solution?

Best

Comment: Duplicate?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/javascript-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value

Comment: possible duplicate of [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Comment: No its not a dupe. OP likes to use `_` library

Comment: Can you please explain with a better example? Perhaps with clear sample input and expected output?

Comment: Do you want to have only two items at a time in `items`?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand completely. Why don't you use object instead of array?

```
var items = {'country': 'US', 'language': 'English'};
```

Then, when you add another country to items by assigning `items.country = 'UK';` the previous country would be overwritten, thus you would always end up with only one item from countries and one item from languages in items object.