# Checking a value in textbox with the array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to write a HTMl page using javascript, in which an Array will store some values. There will be a text box on the screen.

User need to enter a value in the text box. If that values is there in the array. Then it should display "Value is there in the array" or else not found.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var cars = ["abc", "def", "ghi","jkl"];
</script>
</head>

<body>
Enter a value <input type="text"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you assigning the value of input box to array? Can you show your code..

Comment: how about some code?

Comment: its just examplee ... i didnt write any code. Am really starting .

Comment: Well what problems are you having? Question seems far too premature if you haven't done anything yet and haven't isolated an actual problem. SO isn't a sounding board for how to get started. In fact there isn't even a question here

Comment: Added my  code n edited the question

Comment: [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Determine whether an array contains a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/javascript-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)

Answer (score 2):

Look, my personal tip would be learning JavaScript. MDN has a great tutorial in JavaScript. [Check it here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)

Now, answering your question:

First, you'll need to have an event to detect text changes. We'll be using the HTML [`onchange`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event.

We can use jQuery's [`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method, for not using loops.
You'll also have to add an ID to your element.

Full solution:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Enter a value: <input type="text" id="carInput" onchange="textChanged()"></p>
<p id="onListText"></p>
<script>
var cars = ["abc", "def", "ghi","jkl"];
var textChanged = function(){
  var inputText = $("#carInput").text();
  if($.inArray(inputText, cars) !== -1){
    $("#onListText").text("Yes sir, this car is in our list! :D");
    return;
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Am not getting any output ?

Comment: @gabriel in case you are thinking of why #indexOf is better: http://jsperf.com/in-array-vs-inarray-vs-indexof

Comment: @Calvintwr `Array.prototype.indexOf()` is not available in IE 8 or inferior. This was asked for some sort of homework, clearly(he mentioned the instructor's requirements). And school teachers often use IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are a beginner to JS and HTML.

Firstly, no you do not need AJAX for this. Secondly, I advise that you try to implement something really simple called [List.js](http://www.listjs.com/).

I selected this for you because I think it is simple enough.

This should get you started.

Comment: It is an assignment. The instructor told to use AJAX :(

Comment: @MuneebK Do you even know what AJAX is? If so, where will you be getting your data from?

Comment: Then you could use listjs for AJAX as well. I suggest you go through the basics of it first, which is using a static JS array like you did. After you are done with it, you can use AJAX to retrieve JSON data and initialise your list. Good luck.