# conditionalPanel javascript conditions in shiny: is there R %in% operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny application using the `conditionalPanel` function from `shiny` package. The condition should be written in `JavaScript` but  I would like to be able to use a condition as follows (written in R)

```
"TP53" %in% unlist(input$ModelVariables)
```

the documenatation states:

> condition -
>   A JavaScript expression that will be evaluated repeatedly to determine whether the panel should be displayed.

I'm not familiar with `JavaScript` at all. I've tried `input.ModelVariables == 'TP53'` but this doesn't work when `input.ModelVariables` has length bigger than 1.

My `sidebarPanel` fragment with `conditionalPanel` is below

```
                    checkboxGroupInput("ModelVariables", 
                                       label = h3("Which variables to view?"),
                                       choices = list( "cohort",
                                                       "stage",        
                                                       "therapy",             
                                                       "TP53",
                                                       "MDM2" ),
                                       selected = list("TP53")
                                  ),
                    conditionalPanel(condition = "'TP53' in unlist(input.ModelVariables)",
                                     checkboxGroupInput("ModelVariablesTP53", 
                                                        label = h3("Which mutations to view?"),
                                                        choices = list( "Missense",
                                                                        "Other",        
                                                                        "WILD"),
                                                        selected = list("Missense",
                                                                        "Other",        
                                                                        "WILD")
                                                        )
```

Comment: Have you tried `'TP53' in input.ModelVariables` in JavaScript?

Comment: This `'TP53' in input.ModelVariables ` doesn't work since `input.ModelVariables` is a list.  And `condition="'TP53' in unlist(input.ModelVariables)"` makes condtitionalPanel permanent.

Comment: I've updated my question with more code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/javascript-determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value) this condition should work (and it works for me)

`condition = "input.ModelVariables.indexOf('TP53') > -1"`

Comment: This is awesome, was looking for this exact answer for a while.