# condition as a vector in conditionalPanel using shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Is it possible to ask in `condition` within  `conditionalPanel`  whether the input of a `selectedInput` belongs to a vector.

It is clear to me that `condition` is a `JavaScript` object and here is a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637285/conditionalpanel-javascript-conditions-in-shiny-is-there-r-in-operator-in-jav). However, my problem is a littel bit different. 
I made a simple example:

```
#  ----
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

var array1 = ['a','c', 'f'];
# header ----
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Example")

#sidebar ----
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = T)

#body ----
body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      selectInput(
        inputId = "control", 
        label = "choose something:",
        choices = c("a", 
                    "b", 
                    "c", 
                    "d", 
                    "e",
                    "f"),
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    )
  ),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.control.indexOf(array1) > -1",
    textInput(inputId = "first", label = "first test")
  )

)

# all ui ----
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = header, 
  sidebar = sidebar, 
  body = body
)

# server ----
server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {


})
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I defined an js-array

```
var array1 = ['a','c', 'f'];
```

however it dose not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned `multiple` to `FASLE` because I'm not sure what's the desired condition in your mind if there is overlap.

How it works is that you need to insert your javascript array in your UI first.
Also, your javascript syntax in the condition is wrong, the correct one should be:`array1.indexOf(input.control) > -1`

The following example works.

```r
#  ----
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# header ----
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Example")

#sidebar ----
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = T)

#body ----
body <- dashboardBody(
  # insert javascript code in UI -----------------------
  tags$head(
    tags$script("var array1 = ['a','c', 'f'];")
  ),

  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 12,
      selectInput(
        inputId = "control", 
        label = "choose something:",
        choices = c("a", 
                    "b", 
                    "c", 
                    "d", 
                    "e",
                    "f"),
        multiple = FALSE
      )
    )
  ),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "array1.indexOf(input.control) > -1", # change code here
    textInput(inputId = "first", label = "first test")
  )

)

# all ui ----
ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = header, 
  sidebar = sidebar, 
  body = body
)

# server ----
server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```