# Traversing through array in an IF-conditional in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a very lightweight search functionality that takes the following:

```
if (searchStr == people.first_name ||
    searchStr == people.last_name || 
    searchStr == people.job || 
    searchStr == people.skills.forEach(function(x) { return x })) {
  Results.push(people)
}
```

`searchStr` is the search string; 'people' is a person object that has a single first and last name and a job, but only one of those thats an array is people.skills -- is there anyway I can traverse through that array in the if-conditional with an anonymous function?

Comment: Are you just trying to see if `searchStr` exists in `people.skills`? Why wouldn't you just use `indexOf`?

Comment: Note `forEach` ignores the value returned by the callback. And then, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Well map would return a new array wouldn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.some` to evaluate whether a condition is true on at least one entry in an array. This is better than `Array.prototype.filter` because it will exit early on the first entry to evaluate as true.

```
if (searchStr == people.first_name ||
    searchStr == people.last_name || 
    searchStr == people.job || 
    people.skills.some(function(x) { return searchStr == x })) {
  Results.push(people)
}
```

`Array.prototype.some` is new in Ecmascript 5 which is [fairly well supported now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

---

You could potentially improve on your search by doing a partial term search instead of an exact search by switching your equality comparisons with `Array.prototype.indexOf` to see if the string *contains* the search term.

```
if (contains(people.first_name, searchStr) ||
    contains(people.last_name, searchStr) || 
    contains(people.job, searchStr) || 
    people.skills.some(function(x) { return contains(x, searchStr); })) {
  Results.push(people)
}

function contains(a, b) {
  return a.indexOf(b) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked! And to clarify, 'return searchStr == x' is returning true if there is a match and if there is a match, that person is pushed into Results[], correct?

Comment: Indeed, it does. However, consider using `indexOf` as per my answer, as it's less verbose. The `some` method is usually used to perform more complex queries.

Answer (score 3):

The [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method serves this purpose:

```
if (searchStr == people.first_name ||
    searchStr == people.last_name || 
    searchStr == people.job || 
    people.skills.some(function(skill) {
      return searchStr == skill;
    })) {
  Results.push(people)
}
```

But using an anonymous function is unnecessary in this case. We can use the [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```
if (searchStr == people.first_name ||
    searchStr == people.last_name || 
    searchStr == people.job || 
    people.skills.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) {
  Results.push(people)
}
```

or, more idiomatically:

```
    people.skills.indexOf(searchStr)+1
```

Be aware that the [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Every), [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Some), [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ForEach), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter), [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) methods are a part of ECMAScript 5 and are therefore not supported in older browsers supporting only ECMAScript <=3.1. You should use [a polyfill](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim), if this is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181586/670377) to determine if a value exists in the array using javascript, if you really have to traverse the array, then use the some function like @DanielImms recommend.

```
if (searchStr == people.first_name ||
    searchStr == people.last_name || 
    searchStr == people.job || 
    people.skills.indexOf(searchStr)>-1) {
  Results.push(people)
}
```

Comment: The `-1` should probably be `+1`. Your statement returns `false` only when the `searchStr` is the first member of the `people.skills` array.

Comment: @Witiko: My mistake, I forgot the `>` symbol :) And you mean the `+1` should be `-1` right?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `Array.reduce()`, which returns a single value.

Try this:

```
if (searchStr == people.first_name ||
    searchStr == people.last_name || 
    searchStr == people.job || 
    people.skills.reduce(function(p,c) {
       return p || (searchStr == c);
      },false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var searchSkills = [].concat.apply([], people.skills);

if (searchStr == people.first_name ||
    searchStr == people.last_name || 
    searchStr == people.job || 
    searchSkills.indexOf(searchStr) >= 0 {
  Results.push(people)
}
```

I'll leave this up for posterity's sake, but this method probably would only be useful if `people.skills` is multi-dimensional.

As a side-note, I'd suspect `indexOf` is much more performant than a `filter` `map` or `some` execution.

Answer (score 1):

And for the sake of thoroughness, if you were on the cutting edge and using Ecmascript 7, you could use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
if (searchStr == people.first_name ||
    searchStr == people.last_name || 
    searchStr == people.job || 
    people.skills.includes(searchStr)
)
```