# Check and add an element into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add an element in to an array if it is not already in the array?

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

I read that push() could be used to add items but I'm not sure how to check if an item is already in the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine whether an array contains a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)

Comment: `indexOf` has known issues in  IE8. You are using jQuery so it is safe to use `jQuery.inArray()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

if (fruits.indexOf('coconut') === -1) {
  fruits.push('coconut');
}
```

This will check if "coconut" is in the array, if it's not then `indexOf` will return `-1`, which will cause the if statement to run. Therefore pushing "coconut" into the array.

`-1` means "not found".

To check if an item is in an array, just do:

```
if (fruits.indexOf('coconut')) {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: @Bekki it checkes "equal value and equal type".

Comment: thanks. how do I check if an element is not in an array?

Answer (score 3):

You can use jquery [**.inArray()**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

//check if is already in the array
if (jQuery.inArray("Banana", fruits) === -1) {
  fruits.push("Banana");
}

console.log(fruits);//prints out ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks. Could you briefly say why `===` instead of `==` and what's `-1`

Comment: why use jQuery for such simple task ??

Comment: Ye a bit overkill if jQuery isn't already being used. Also not as readable I would say when you don't know the parameters of inArray(). But a good solution nontheless.

Comment: @Mateutek for being sure it will be cross browser compatible

Comment: @Bekki `===` in js is to compare by the type. Also `.inArray()` method returns `-1` when the given element doesn't represent in the array.

Answer (score 1):

With `indexOf` method you can check the position of the given element in the array. If `-1` is returned, it's not in the array.

```
if (fruits.indexOf('New item') === -1) {
  fruits.push('New item')
}
```

Comment: Why `add()` and not `push()` ?

Comment: @Bekki It was a mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf()` searches for a particular element in the array and returns -1 if element is not present.
Then after checking that you can put the element in array using `push()`

```
   if(fruits.indexOf('element to be added') === -1)
             fruits.push('element to be added');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if *item to enter* exists or not.
For that use `.indexOf()` function.

If not, use `.push()` to add a new item.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/t4by6vss/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    var item_to_enter="Grapes";
    var item_should_not_enter="Apple";

    if(fruits.indexOf(item_to_enter)<0)
    {
        fruits.push(item_to_enter);
    }
    if(fruits.indexOf(item_should_not_enter)<0)
    {
        fruits.push(item_should_not_enter);
    }
    console.log(fruits);
});
```