# TypeScript simplest way to check if item exists in array like C# Linq Any ( using any library )

Tags: typescript

TypeScript simplest way to check if item exists in array like C# Linq Any ( using any library ). Something like

```html
var myArray=[1,2,3,4];

var is_3_Exist=myArray.Any(x=> x==3);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine whether an array contains a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)

Answer (score 56):

Use `.some`:

`myArray.some(x=>x==3);`

Comment: Sorry, myArray.some(x=>x==3); is not supported in old browser

Comment: Polyfill it : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill

Comment: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_some

Answer (score 5):

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/vktawbzg/

**NPM:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/linqscript

**GITHUB:** https://github.com/sevensc/linqscript

Take a look at my Github Repository. It would be great if you guys can help to improve it!
https://github.com/sevensc/linqscript

Syntax:

```
list.Any(c => c.Name === ("Apple"))
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to link your linqscript to already existing TS files? And what should I do to call this stuff from my code?

Comment: i made a npm package, get it there:
`npm install linqscript`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/linqscript

You need to import the namespace. See the Readme for more infos.

Comment: Ok, I saw the package but don't quite understand how to use it from my TS code. Could you please drop a line of details?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the findindex method :

```
if( myArray.findIndex(x => x === 3) >= 0) {
    // foud myArray element equals to 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only thing you need to do you should go for .some (with polyfill) if you however want Linq functionality for other things as well you should take a look at https://github.com/ReactiveX/IxJS.

Comment: Its nuget package is not working. I found <a href="https://www.nuget.org/packages/TypeScriptLinq">TypeScriptLinq</a> working.

Comment: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/IxJS should work, it is a repo maintained by microsoft.

Comment: What is its Nuget link ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a TypeScript library for LINQ.

It is called **ts-generic-collections-linq**.

Providing strongly-typed, queryable collections such as:

- List
- Dictionary

Easy to use.

NPM

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-generic-collections-linq

Sample linq query:

```js
let myArray=[1,2,3,4];

let list = new List(myArray);

let is_3_Exist = list.any(x => x==3);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to fiddle more with prototype to get started writing such 'extension methods':

```
   if (!Array.prototype.Any) {
  Array.prototype.Any = function <T>(condition: predicate<T>): boolean {
    if (this.length === 0)
      return false;
    let result: boolean = false;
    for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
      const element = this[index];
      if (condition(element)) {
        result = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

The prototype allows you to add functionality to arrays like and call the functionality easy:

let anyEven = [5, 3, 1, 7, 3, 4, 7].Any(x => x % 2== 0); //true