# issue with javascript .indexOf()

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with how to check if an arry contains a value.

html:

```
    var newprodata = [];
    var alreadyUsedIds = [];
    angular.forEach(prodata, function(line) {       
        if(line.name === proName || line.brand === proBrand){
            //if (line.id === 183)  {
            var id = parseInt(line.id);
            console.log("line.id",id);
            console.log("alreadyUsedIds",alreadyUsedIds);
            console.log( "alreadyUsedIds.indexOf("+id+")", alreadyUsedIds.indexOf(id) );
            //}
            if (alreadyUsedIds.indexOf(id) > -1){
                console.log("on record pas");
            } else {
                //console.log("line.id",line.id);
                console.log("on record");
                alreadyUsedIds.push(parseInt(id));
                newprodata.push(line);
            }
        }
    });
```

here's my console `output`:

```
alreadyUsedIds [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
0: 24
1: 25
2: 26
3: 27
4: 28
5: 29
6: 30
7: 31
8: 32
9: 33
10: 34
11: 35
12: 36
13: 183
length: 14__proto__: Array[0]      filters.js:46 
alreadyUsedIds.indexOf(183) -1
```

, it should not be '-1' because '183' is in the array !!!

Moreover, if I set a breakpoint, and check manually I get:  alreadyUsedIds.indexOf(183) = 13

Comment: It's not clear at all what that mix of code and output is trying to tell us.  Please can you split it up into your code, expected output, actual output?

Comment: there is an similar topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value?answertab=active#tab-top and you could find answer there!

Comment: Are you looking at the value, before the array is updated or something like that ?

Comment: I can't see `183` in `alreadyUsedIds`. I doubt you're retrieving the index in a loop, and `183` doesn't exist in the array at the time you're reading the index, but exists at the time console really logs the values. Notice, that console.log is asynchronous. Please show some real code you have.

Comment: i think you should make a jsfiddle for better understanding

Comment: I don't see any actual code here, just what appears as some debug info. Can't really help without actual code.

Comment: I added my code. There is a .push() on the array, into a angular.forEach...is there something asynchronous that I don't know about ? Because the issue is clearly that at the time of the indexOf(), 183 is not yet into the array...though it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You use `alreadyUsedIds = [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]`
However this array does not contain the element `183` so you wont find it there

Example on how it works:

```js
var alreadyUsedIds = [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36];

// returns -1, because there is no element 183
console.log( alreadyUsedIds.indexOf(183) )

// add 183 to the end of the array
alreadyUsedIds.push(183) 

// returns 13, because the element 183 is at position 13
console.log( alreadyUsedIds.indexOf(183) )
```

Comment: The `=` sign is not shown in the console for arrays. That code is the OP's console output, not actual code.

Comment: no because there's a weid behavior, at the time of the console output, 183 is not yet in the array

Comment: in my code? At the first output it is not in the array (as you can see the array does not contain 183 when its defined), but in the second it is (we added it to the array).

Answer (score 0):

If alreadyUsedIds actually contains 183 it works fine, demonstration in jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5qknqgex/

```
var alreadyUsedIds = [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 183];
console.log(alreadyUsedIds.indexOf(183));
```

The only explanation is that your array doesn't contain 183 at the time of console.log

Comment: yes that's it, at the time of the console log, it's not yet in the array, but I don't really understand this. ... is .push() an async function ?

Answer (score -1):

it's working here

https://jsfiddle.net/jtc2wppu/2/

```
var alreadyUsedIds = [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 183];
console.log(alreadyUsedIds.indexOf(183));
```

Comment: Not sure what is "working", but surely that's not OP meant

Comment: this is exactly the code that OP is looking for? What are you talking about?

Comment: No. OP is clearly saying 183 should be in the array. Dunno how, but that's another story. (also downvoted the question itself)