# AngularJs check weather Array containing an item or not

Tags: angularjs

I have array of name:
`$scope.myArray` with some values.
Now I want to check an Item is present in array or not,
If it is not present then I want to push that item into array and If that item is already in array then I don't want to push it.
Please tell me how to do this ?

Comment: Please kindly search in SO before asking a question.

Comment: I didn't get the proper  answer in SO without filter

Comment: Here is how you search in Google for SO - [site:stackoverflow.com javascript check array contains](https://www.google.com/webhp?&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+javascript+check+array+contains)

Comment: have you try indexOf method ?

Comment: [SO post: determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)

Comment: @SherlockedNguyen can you please explain it with one example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($scope.myArray.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    $scope.myArray.push(item)
}
```

You can read about [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for more details. Also, checkout [underscore js](http://underscorejs.org/) for some readily available functions.

Comment: here if I want exact opposite condition then how it should be ?

Comment: Add item if it is already present?