# Check the array has empty element or not

Tags: javascript

How can I check the array has empty element or not?
Imagine this array,

```
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', , 'd'];
```

the arr[2] is `undefined`. I want to check this. If the element has empty element, return 'true' or return false. Maybe like this,

```
function hasEmptyElement(array){
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (typeof arr[i] == 'undefined'){
          return true; 
          // and then ?
          // should I use double for loop or helper variable?
        }
    }
}
```

I confuse how can I do this. Please help me the clevers.

Comment: `if(arr[i] == undefined)` this should work

Comment: Check also null with !arr[i] === true

Comment: check the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As of ES2016, you should use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
const array = ["a", "b", , "d"];
array.includes(undefined); // true
```

(You don't need to write `undefined`, but this makes it more clear what's happening.)

Note that this method treats slots valued `undefined` and *empty* slots the same, although they're not. If you need to differentiate these two cases as well, starting from ES2017, you can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) making the following expression `true` if there are empty slots in the array:

```
Object.values(array).length !== array.length; // true
```

Comment: Do you know why array.indexOf(undefined) is -1?

Comment: @James: Because the third element of `array` isn't actually `undefined`, but rather an empty slot. `Array.prototype.includes`, however, treats empty slots and slots valued `undefined` the same.

Comment: will fail for `["a", "b", undefined, "d"]` since the third slot is not empty.

Comment: @vsync: The answer above has been pointing this out for over half a decade and even provides a solution for this edge case, have you read it?

Answer (score 23):

First, note the difference between empty slots and slots with undefined value:

```
var arr = [/*empty slot*/, undefined];
Object.keys(arr); // ["1"] but not "0"
"0" in arr; // false
"1" in arr; // true
```

ES5 array methods skip empty slots. ES6 `[].includes` does not.

That means you can use

```
arr.includes(undefined); // has empty slot OR contains undefined value
arr.indexOf(undefined) > -1; // contains undefined value
```

If you want to test only if there are empty slots, you can iterate manually with a `for` loop and check whether all indices between 0 and the length of the array are present, e.g. with `in` operator.

```
(function() {
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) if(!(i in arr)) return true;
  return false;
})(); // has empty slot
```

Or you can also use ES5 array methods and check if they skipped an index.

```
var n = 0;
arr.some((_,i) => i !== n++); // has empty slot
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', , 'd'];

document.write(arr.findIndex(e => e === undefined) > -1);
```

Comment: This solves the problem of finding the first empty or undefined index, which is the first part of my problem, though it's technically beyond the OP's question.  Thanks for going one step beyond.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var hasAnyEmptyElement = arr.filter(function(val){ return (typeof val) != "undefined" }).length != arr.length;
```

DEMO

```js
var arr = [1,2];
arr[4] = 2;

var hasAnyEmptyElement = arr.filter(function(val){ return (typeof val) != "undefined" }).length != arr.length;

alert(hasAnyEmptyElement);
```

Comment: `val == "undefined"`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
function hasEmptyElement(array){
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (!(i in array)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The main point of this implementation is that it makes difference between `[1,,3]` and `[1, undefined, 3]`

Comment: Your claim that it "makes difference" is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

```
var temp = arr.filter(item => item);
```

This will give you a new array with below elements:
`["a", "b", "d"]`

The above solution will help to remove empty as well as null values.

Comment: This is unreliable because there may be items in the array such as the number 0 or the boolean false. instead use arr.filter(item => item !== undefined).length

Answer (score 1):

Simple implementation using set

```
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', , 'd'];
// Using Set from es6
var arraySet = new Set(arr)
arraySet.has(undefined) // returns true
```

Thanks!

Comment: this is also showing true for:

`var arr = [ 'a', 'b', undefined];

var arraySet = new Set(arr)

arraySet.has(undefined)
// true`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```js
var arr = [ 'a', 'b',, 'd'];
function myfunc(arr) {
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (!(i in arr)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
alert( myfunc(arr));
```

Comment: I think you should edit your answer as it makes no sense and has very little information

Answer (score 0):

For ES5- you can do

```
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', , 'd'];
arr.filter(function() { return true }).length === arr.length
```

That is going to return `false` if there is a `undefined`

ES2015 check [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Also let us know the beauty of `return true`

Answer (score 0):

```
`Check null/undefined values in Array`

function checkNullValue(a) {
                    if (typeof (a) == 'undefined' || a === null) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }

     }

    var arrayMonthVal = ['1','2',,'6','null', '8'];

    var pass = arrayMonthVal.some(checkNullValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to know if a given array element was empty and this page helped me derive the following solution:

```
/** Determine if an array element is empty.
 *  @param {*[]} arr
 *  @param {number} [i] If not provided, check entire arr for empty.
 *  @return {boolean}
 */
const hasEmpty = (arr, i) => 0<=i 
  ? !arr.some((_, j) => j==i) 
  : Object.values(arr).length!==arr.length;
```

Answer (score -1):

Making it simple you can use the below comparison for achieving the same.

```
function hasEmptyElement(array){
   for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
       if(my_arr[i] === "")   
          return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Your code says that there is an empty element if, and only if, it doesn't contain the empty string.

Comment: yes Oriol , I accept that the user was referring to the character literal that are to be checked. And to generalise we can substitute the "" with null keyword to check for nulls that are I suppose generic to all types

Comment: The [null value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.11) belongs to the [Null type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.12). It's not generic.

Answer (score -4):

hello try this....

```
 if (typeof arr[i] == 'NULL'){
      return true; 
}
```

hope this may work

Comment: `typeof` never returns `'NULL'`.

Comment: What does the `i` here?