# Why Array.some() method behaving differently?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having an array which contains empty elements.

```
let arr = ['item 1', 'item 2', , 'item 3', , 'item 4', 'item 5'];
```

I am trying to find out if there is any empty element in an array by using [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method but it returns false.

```js
// Input array
const arr = ['item 1', 'item 2', , 'item 3', , 'item 4', 'item 5'];

// If you see in console, empty element has been filled with undefined
console.log(arr); // ["item 1","item 2",undefined,"item 3",undefined,"item 4","item 5"]

// Now I am just checking if is there any falsy value in an array. Ideally it should return true as we have undefined values in an arr but it is returning `false`.
console.log(arr.some(item => !item)); // false
```

There are so many other ways to check if is there any `undefined` values in an array but here I am specifically asking about the [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) behaviour. If I will explicitly replace the empty elements with undefined, then it will return `true`.

```js
const arr = ['item 1', 'item 2', undefined, 'item 3', undefined, 'item 4', 'item 5'];

console.log(arr.some(item => !item)); // true
```

Why is it behaving like that? Please don't provide any alternate solutions as I am aware about other alternate solutions.

Comment: sparse items are not iterated. what other approach do you want?

Comment: @NinaScholz, but in console and while map and print the index, I can see it iterates over an empty elements as well and assign undefined instead of the index. Here is the demo : https://jsfiddle.net/179f8y2o/

Comment: @RohìtJíndal It doesn't. What you are seeing is that JSFiddle displays those values as `undefined`. If you look at the console, [those values remain untouched/empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrH97.png).

Comment: @RohìtJíndal - Try this in your console: ```[1, , , 4].some((value, index) => { console.log(`Index ${index}: ${value}`); return value === undefined;});``` Note that you only see `Index 0: 1` and `Index 3: 4`, you don't see anything for the two gaps, because `some` doesn't call the callback for them. And that means your callback never returns `true`, so you get `false` from `some`. Compare with ```[1, , , 4, undefined].some((value, index) => { console.log(`Index ${index}: ${value}`); return value === undefined;});``` Notice that you see `Index 4: undefined` and `some` returns `true`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#description):

> The some() method executes the callbackFn function once for each element present in the array until it finds the one where callbackFn returns a truthy value (a value that becomes true when converted to a Boolean). If such an element is found, some() immediately returns true. Otherwise, some() returns false. **callbackFn is invoked only for indexes of the array with assigned values. It is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.**

You can see that here:

```js
const arr = ['item 1', 'item 2', , 'item 3', , 'item 4', 'item 5'];
console.log(arr.some((item, index) => {
  console.log(item, index);
  return !item
}));
```

---

> If I will explicitly replace the empty elements with undefined, then it will return true.

That's the difference between "never assigned a value" and "been assigned the `undefined` value".

Answer (score 0):

The elements are actually `empty` and `not undefined`

```
const arr = ['item 1', 'item 2', , 'item 3', , 'item 4', 'item 5'];

// If you see in console, empty element has been filled with undefined
console.log(arr); 
VM146:4 (7) ['item 1', 'item 2', empty, 'item 3', empty, 'item 4', 'item 5']
```

Thats the reason the `some` script behaves differently. This thread does a good job on explaining stuff

[Check the array has empty element or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622064/check-the-array-has-empty-element-or-not)

Comment: If you see in the code snippet in my post, empty elements are `filled` with `undefined`.

Comment: Try viewing the same on chrome console.. they are not undefined.. but empty