# Javascript, filtering array with an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, filter

I need to filter an array1, with each element in my array 2. Both arrays can have a random number of elements.

```
 array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
 array2 = [1,3,5];
 filteredArray = [];

 array2.forEach(function(x){
   filteredArray = array1.filter(function(y){
     return y !== x;
   });
 });
 return filteredArray;
 //should return -> [2,4]
 // returns [1,2,3,4]
```

How can I filter an array with all elements in another array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value - you can use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use arrays indexOf method

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = [1,3,5];
var filteredArray = array1.filter(function(x) {
    return array2.indexOf(x) < 0;
});
```

or, for sexy people, use `!~` with `indexOf`

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = [1,3,5];
var filteredArray = array1.filter(function(x) {
    return !~array2.indexOf(x);
});
```

Comment: `!array2.includes(x)` *(ECMAScript 2016)*

Comment: yes, with ecmascript 2016 ... no browser is 100% ecmascript 2015 yet, so, hell, let's just jump to ecmascript 2020 :p

Comment: It's just a method. Patching is easy, even without a transpiler.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @squint - I was kidding around :p

Comment: No problem... just sayin'... ;)

Comment: in fact, array#filter wont work in IE8 or less ... so all those ATM machines would crash with this code :p

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way would be:

```
var filteredArray = array1.filter(function(item) {
    return !(array2.indexOf(item) >= 0);
});
```

Comment: that wont work because 0...n should result in false, and -1 in true

Comment: Still doesn't work. If you put in `return !(array2.indexOf(item) >= 0);` that should do the trick.

Comment: sexy people use `!~`

Comment: isn't `!( ... >= 0)` just `... < 0`

Comment: yes, as will ! >= 0 ... 0 >= 0 is true, !true is false ... trust me ... `!(a.indexOf(b) >= 0)` is 100% identical to `a.indexOf(b) < 0` ... or, more simply ... `!(a >= 0)` === `a < 0`

Comment: @TarunDugar: Think that through for just a moment longer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array2 = [1, 3, 5];
filteredArray = [];

filteredArray = array1.filter(function (y) {
  return array2.indexOf(y) < 0;
 });
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf()` to check if the `array2` item is in `array1` then only add it to `filteredArray` if it is:

```
 array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
 array2 = [1,3,5];
 filteredArray = [];

 array2.forEach(function(x){
     if (array1.indexOf(array2[x] > -1) {
         filteredArray.push(array2[x]);
     }
 });
 return filteredArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6, you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for it.

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    array2 = [1, 3, 5],
    filteredArray = array1.filter((set => a => !set.has(a))(new Set(array2)));

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: We can make it even more convoluted..! How about `filteredArray = array1.filter(function(set,a) {return !set.has(a)}.bind(null,new Set(array2)));`..?

Comment: in this case, you could use `new Set(...)` as this args.

Answer (score 0):

All `indexOf` no play makes me a dull boy...

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5],
    array2 = [1,3,5],
  filtered = array1.filter(e => !array2.includes(e));
console.log(filtered);
```