# Checking if an element exists in current array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to check through multiple paragraphs that contain input fields, i loop through each input field checking data has been entered, however i have groups of check boxes i need to check to see if at least one has been selected.

i have a loop through each input element and checking the parents are different, if not i am trying to store these in an array for validation later on, the problem i am having is the input filed with the same parent is still being added to the array and the value being stored is `jQuery.fn.init[1]`.

```
$elementParent = $(currentElement).parent();
if(jQuery.inArray($elementParent, $checkboxArray) == -1)
{
   $checkboxArray.push($elementParent);
}
```

Further on in the code i get an error with the `.each` function, error given: `Uncaught TypeError: $checkboxArray.each is not a function`

```
$checkboxArray.each(function(index,checkboxParent){
$checkboxItems = checkboxParent.find('input[checkboxG=checkbox_group]');
$checkboxItems.each(function(index,item) {
if($(item.prop("checked")))
{
    $checkboxError = false;
}
});
if ($checkboxError == true)
{
   alert("error");  
}               
});
```

i have made a simple version of my error. https://jsfiddle.net/1b5ufnev/

Comment: because i am checking if 1 checkbox inside a group of checkboxes is selected as a minimum.

Comment: Please provide a js fiddle or other example that can be reviewed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine whether an array contains a value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)

Comment: did you initialized $checkboxArray first?

Comment: @adrianC yes the array is initialised and is adding the parents, however if the parents are the same it still adds.

Comment: it is hard to say, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @adrianC i have added a fiddle example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bd0f92ej/1/ each() function is not a standart function of an array. It's a jquery function so you should use $.each()

Comment: i literally just solved it, thanks for your help but if you write an answer i can accept it