# How to check if an array doesn't contain a string and use it as condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
var name = document.getElementById("namebox").value;

if (array.includes(name) == false) {
   alert(name + " is not in record.")
}
```

that didn't work and will always return false, how to express the check in other ways? please enlighten, thank you very much

Comment: what browser did that not work in?

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)

Comment: Can you show  your `Array` and working snippet

Comment: codepen.io's default engine

Comment: `codepen.io's default engine` what is this a response to? .... again, what browser did that not work in

Comment: oh sorry it is Opera...

Comment: https://codepen.io/quanquanah/pen/wgGXgR?editors=1010

Comment: which version of Opera

Comment: Version 46.0.2597.14 (PGO)

Comment: *that didn't work* in what way?

Comment: nevermind ... your code (in this question) is fine, your array (students) does not contain what you think it contains ... e,g it contains `student1,score1`,`student2,score2` ... searching for `student1` will fail, as `student1` !== `student1,score1`

Comment: edited... sorry for the bad question because I am a learning novice... the downvotes are saddening...

Comment: the issue is, that the code you've presented does **not** contain enough of your code to even duplicate the issue - the fault is not with that logic, but with the **data** you are actually working with

Comment: @JaromandaX oh... thanks... so ".includes" doesn't check the content as string but more like a == comparison?....

Comment: yes, more like that - you'll want to use `Array.prototype.some` with a callback function that checks `Atring.prototype.indexOf` - perhaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because your array is like

```
[ "name1,score1", "name2,score2"]
```

searching for "name1" using includes wont work

you'll want something like

```
if (!array.some(item => item.split(',')[0] === name)) {
    alert(name + " is not in record.")
}
```

or in pre ES2015

```
if (!array.some(function (item) {
    return item.split(',')[0] === name;
})) {
    alert(name + " is not in record.");
}
```

or if your browser doesn't have Array.prototype.some

```
if (array.filter(function (item) {
    return item.split(',')[0] === name;
}).length === 0) {
    alert(name + " is not in record.");
}
```

Comment: Read array.prototype.some documentation

Comment: The arrow function odd probably alien to you as well. Right

Comment: I've added some possibly easier to understand code - `item` could be any name, it's just each entry in the array for each iteration of `.some`

Comment: I was guessing... array is the name of the array students[]... and item is the element of the array... students[i][0] ?... and I will have to put them in a loop to check?

Comment: dear @Jaromanda X, I failed to understand how to use your methods just by reading documentation (language barrier and intelligence difference may be), but I managed to think of a way that is by constructing a temporary Array and then push all the student[i][0] (names) into it, then only do the checking... other than splitting method you tried to teach me, I also found array flattening methods but I really couldn't understand just by reading... thanks anyhow =)

Comment: to be honest, your original design is flawed. Rather than adding "name, score" onto an array, I would be adding an object something like `{student: "name", score: number}` - that way you can find the student using `array.find(item=> item.student === name)`

Comment: I've never used object before and it's the next topic I will start learning =) thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may try

```
if (array.indexOf(name) == -1) {
   alert(name + " is not in record.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using includes():**

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const valueToCheck = 6;

if (!array.includes(valueToCheck)) {
    console.log("The array does not contain the value.");
} else {
    console.log("The array contains the value.");
}
```

**Using indexOf():**

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const valueToCheck = 6;

if (array.indexOf(valueToCheck) === -1) {
    console.log("The array does not contain the value.");
} else {
    console.log("The array contains the value.");
}
```