# Is there a Javascript equivalent to Python's in conditional operator?

Tags: javascript

Is there a Javascript equivalent to Python's `in` conditional operator?

```
good = ['beer', 'pizza', 'sushi']
thing = 'pizza'
if thing in good:
    print 'hurray'
```

What would be a good way to write the above Python code in Javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine whether an array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `.includes`:

```js
const good = ['beer', 'pizza', 'sushi']
const thing = 'pizza';
if (good.includes(thing)) console.log('hurray');
```

Note that this is entirely separate from Javascript's `in` operator, which checks for if something is a property of an object:

```js
const obj = { foo: 'bar'}
const thing = 'foo';
if (thing in obj) console.log('yup');
```

Note that `includes` is from ES6 - make sure to include a polyfill. If you can't do that, you can use the old, less semantic `indexOf`:

```js
const good = ['beer', 'pizza', 'sushi']
const thing = 'pizza';
if (good.indexOf(thing) !== -1) console.log('hurray');
```

Comment: Never knew there was an "includes" method! I usually use indexOf

Comment: But `indexOf` is not entirely equivalent to `contains`.

Comment: The JS `includes` syntax is not quite as nice as Python IMO.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using JavaScript ES6, I believe that [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is what you're looking for. If you need support for older versions of JS, then you can use [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (or use a polyfill for Array.contains).

```
// Array.includes()
if (yourArray.includes("some value")) {
    // Do stuff
}

// Array.indexOf()
if (yourArray.indexOf("some value") > -1) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple google search will answer your question. Found this in google #1 search https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp.

You can use `indexOf` method in javascript to find elements in your array.

Comment: This is a comment and/or a close vote or down vote, not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can check using [indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method.

Example:

```
const good = ['beer', 'pizza', 'sushi']
const thing = 'pizza';

if(good.indexOf(thing) !== -1)
//do something
```

if it's matches, will return the very first index. If not, will return `-1`.

Quick note:
`indexOf()` method comes with ECMAScript 1 so it will be compatible with all browsers. But `includes()`
 method comes witch ECMAScript 6 and maybe cannot be compatible on some platforms/older browser versions.