# jQuery is() or has() on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to detect if array of elements **$a** contains the element **$c** where:

```
var $a=$('#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4');
var $c=$('#b3');
```

but no `$c.is($a)` or `$a.has($c)` works.
Looking for a jQuery answer.

Comment: Did you try `.filter` ? `$a.filter($c).length > 0`  (edit: changed to `.filter` rather than `.find` as it looks like `#b3` is not a child item (implied by the use of "contains" in the question)).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1473737/2181514

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: might not be a full solution you're after but you can do `$.inArray(needle, haystack)`

Comment: @freedomn-m publish it as answer since is the correct one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop through your first selector and check for all its elements individually.

Here I use jQuery `.filter()` method to search for the element, combined with `.length` to check if the element was found.

```js
let $a=$('#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4');
let $c=$('#b3');
let $d=$('#b5');

let result = !!$a.filter((_,e) => $(e).is($c)).length;
console.log('$c in $a ? '+result);

let result2 = !!$a.filter((_,e) => $(e).is($d)).length;
console.log('$d in $a ? '+result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b1"></div><div id="b2"></div><div id="b3"></div><div id="b4"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
$a.findIndex(x => x === $c) > -1
```

or you can use find in array 
a simple example is 
[this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `selector` property of jQuery object to check that:

```js
var $a=$('#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4');
var $c=$('#b3');
if($a.selector.indexOf($c.selector) !== -1){
  console.log('match');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use inArray()

```
$.inArray($c,$a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this $a.findIndex(x => x === $c) > -1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$a.findIndex(x => x === $c) > -1
```

to get a boolean.

If you want the elements that match use map

```
$a.map(x => { return x === $c })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` for doing that:

```js
var $a=$('#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4');
var $c=$('#b3');
if($a.index($c) > -1){
  console.log('match');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="b1"></div><div id="b2"></div><div id="b3"></div><div id="b4"></div>
```