# How can we check for an iterative if condition inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check for an *if condition* iteratively inside a *for loop*. That means some expressions of i*f conditions* need to be generated iteratively as shown in the below example

```
let union = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let control = [2,4,6]
let result = []
for(let i=0; i<union.length; i++){
  if(union[i] % 2 == 0 && union[i] !== control[i]){
    result.push(union[i])
  }
}
```

In the above example `union[i] !== control[i]` is the conditional expression that need to be validated/generated iteratively. In words we can state the problem as

*result array should contain only even numbers from the union array and it should not contain any element from the control array*

So the result array should be `[8]`

Comment: But 9 isn't an even number..?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo i have edited the question

Comment: Then this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1181575

Comment: To start with, control[i] will cause problems, since its length is different to the length of the union array, i.e what value were you expecting from control[6] ? Do a test and see the result

Comment: Yea that is an erroneous code and it will not give us the expected answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

result array should contain only even numbers from the union array and it should not contain any element from the control array

```
let union = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let control = [2,4,6]
let result = []

union.forEach(item => {
    if(item % 2 == 0 && !control.includes(item)) {
        result.push(item);
    }
});
```

The `.includes` method checks if the item is in the array.

or just a simple filter

```
const result = union.filter(item => item % 2 == 0 && !control.includes(item));
```

Comment: Searching in an array again and again is not an efficient solution, try using a `Set`.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee I agree for a massive array, But for this solution its fine. i think hes just doing some coda katas.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `Array#filter` with a `Set`.

The problem with your code is for every item in `union` you need to check every item in `control`, whether it exists or not, which you are not doing.

And I would recommend using a `Set` instead of searching in an array repeatedly.

```js
const 
  union = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  control = [2, 4, 6],
  result = ((s) => union.filter((u) => !(u&1) && !s.has(u)))(new Set(control));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

1 more option.
remove duplicate item between 2 arrays then just check for even numbers.

```
let union = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let control = [2,4,6]
let result = []

union = union.filter(function(val) {
  return control.indexOf(val) == -1;
});

for(let i=0; i<union.length; i++){
  if(union[i] % 2 == 0){
    result.push(union[i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the check and see if `control.includes(union[i])`. This will be true when control includes the current union variable. This is also true for the other way round, meaning if control includes the union variable, the union variable also contains the control variable. Negate the check with `!` to see if it doesn't include this value.

```js
let union = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
let control = [2,4,6]
let result = []
for(let i=0; i<union.length; i++){
  if(union[i] % 2 == 0 && !control.includes(union[i])){
    result.push(union[i])
  }
}
console.log(result);
```