# vuejs- nested search, return only not matching results

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

Im trying to filter and return only not matching results. Now its returning always a full array. How to make it right?

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      postList: [
        {
          title: "hello",
          info: ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
        },
        {
          title: "goodbye",
          info: ["five", "six"],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
     filteredList() {
      return this.postList.filter((item) => {
        return item.info.some((s) => s != this.search);
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: return `!item.info.includes(this.search)` perhaps? As per [this JavaScript Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181586/) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/)

Comment: I tried to find answer, I kinda helpless now.

Comment: Your example worked fine! Thanks!

Comment: Yours definitely helped. I sometimes could not figure out how to fix my issue with other example. p.s. Thanks again, best wishes!